# How can I get my wireless router to broadcast a LAN connection?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

So I'm trying to set up an internet connection. The way its set up is that a few houses, mine included have an ariel (a nanostation M5) pointed at a common access point. This works fine and I get good speeds out of the LAN connection coming from the aerial.

My question is: How do I then turn that LAN connection from the aerial into a wireless signal using my wireless router? The obvious plug the LAN into the WAN port on the router seems to do nothing.

EDIT: The router I have is a TP-LINK TL WR841N, and I can log in to it on the default 192.168.0.1

Can anyone suggest anything? Are there settings on the router that I have to change in order for this to work?

Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: "The obvious plug the LAN into the WAN port on the router seems to do nothing."  That's what you need to do, but just plugging the wire in the other port isn't going to be enough.  "Are there settings on the router that I have to change in order for this to work?"  Yes, but unfortunately you haven't mentioned your existing network configurations, nor even the model of the router in question, so there's no way for us to help you figure out what they should be set to.  Please edit your question and add more information, otherwise it will most likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, Unfortunately I'm not really sure as to what the current network config settings are.. or what they should be

Comment: "I'm not really sure as to what the current network config settings are.. or what they should be"  Then you're not the person to be setting up that new LAN, and there's no way for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you plug your LAN cable from the aerial into the WAN port, what lights do you observe on the front panel? specifically the WAN light?
is it Off, Solid or Flashing?

As you look at the top of your TP-Link, the WAN light is the 4th from the left.
If your WAN light is "off", then you have no connection, no input from the LAN at all being recognised by the router.

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that the WAN is not configured correctly to accept input from your LAN connection.  You are going to need to go into the setup to check that.  Make sure your computer has a connection to the TP-Link router and then from a browser window, go to http://tplinklogin.net, you'll get a box pop up asking you for username and password ... use the default "admin" and "admin" if you haven't already changed it.

Once you've logged in, go to the "Quick Setup" menu.  The TP-Link has an "auto-detect" function on its WAN setup that **MAY** solve your issues but I wouldn't be holding my breath - nothing is ever that easy!!  Before you click "auto-detect, make sure the LAN cable from the aerial is plugged into the WAN port of the TP-Link .... see how you go with that and post results ...

This may also help you a bit if you don't already have it - [TP-LINK TL WR841N User Manual](http://setuprouter.com/router/tp-link/tl-wr841n/manual-740.pdf)

Comment: @user2891996 - did you manage to fix this issue? or are you still having issues?